# Keeping reference of Controller in View or using listener

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am reading what I think a seminal article about Model-View-Controller (MVC) using Java (lots of people on here already referred to it when discussing about MVC).

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html

Basically, it presents a modified MVC flow, with the Model sending notifications to Controller (not View, as in the traditional way). Controller then passes the notifications on to View for interface updates, or inteprets user interactions' commands and send back to Model.

I have a question regarding the way Controller and View work in tandem. In this article, the author kept a reference to Controller in both of his Views, and directly called methods of Controller in these Views. I was wondering about the rational behind it. Why didn't he implement some ActionListeners in Controller, and let interaction widgets in the Views send signals to these listeners?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of coupling.

If your view has a reference to it's controller, it is coupled to the controller. You would do this if you do not expect your view to ever use a different controller.
With direct access, it is simpler to follow the various code paths.

If you implement a action listener pattern, you are decoupling the view and the controller. A view and controller can exist independently and you could potentially use different controllers for the same view.